# how does itemgetter work? what happens when we initialise it to key

Tags: python, sorting

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = [(5, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, -1), (4, 9)]
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(0))
[(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, -1), (4, 9), (5, 3)]
```

How does this work? is key a function as well? i am confused about what goes behind key=itemgetter(0) ? If some one can explain step by step

Comment: The documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Comment: can not understand that i am afraid!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`itemgetter(..)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is a function that constructs a function. This concept is known in computer science as [*currying* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Currying is very common in *functional* programming languages.

A simplified version of itemgetter would be implemented as follows:

```
def itemgetter(key):
    def f(item):
        return item[key]
    return f
```

So for example if we construct an `itemgetter(1)`, we can then call that function, for example:

```
>>> f = itemgetter(1)
>>> f([1,4,2,5])
4
```

So here `f(..)` will take the second item of the list.

> is key a function as well?

**Yes**, the `key` is a function. As the [documentation of `sorted(..)` [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) says:

> **`key` specifies a function of one argument** that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, `key=str.lower`). The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

Comment: what are the arguments for key function ? 2 what happens when it is looped in order to sort

Comment: @Randy: the argument of the `itemgetter(..)` is the key/index of which you want to obtain the corresponding value. (2) if you call the function multiple times, for each parameter it will obtain the corresponding value.

Comment: That I understood..what is bothering me is that..when we write key=itemgetter(0)...Does it give the 0th index/1st element of all the tuples present in list..i Hope u got my question? i want to know how that key=itemgetter(0) works step by step or does it sort in a go?

Comment: @Randy: python uses the `key` to map all items in the iterable to the mapping of that key, and then sorts the elements based on that mapping. So if `key(item1) < key(item2)`, then `item1` should be placed *before* `item2` in the output list. It uses [*timsort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_sort) for that.

Comment: thank u..one more thing if key is a function, how are we assigning a function to a function, first i thought, key is just a variable used by sorted function to work

Comment: @Randy: key is a parameter, but you can pass anything as a parameter in Python: a module, class, function, integer, etc. These are all objects, and you pass these by copying the address where the object is constructed.

Comment: Correct me if i an wrong. Key is a function which will give the first element of what is passed to it. So when the sort algorithm is run..Key will pass the entire list to it ? or it will pass one item from list and get the first element from that item and then pass the second item to it and get the second elememnt and so on and then sort those element in order ( with their pair)

Comment: Hey can you just check this for a min!!

Comment: @Randy: key will be called on every item of the iterable. So it will each time obtain a 2-tuple here, and each time return the first element of that 2-tuple.

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated!!